# In Java, can the number of variables passed in value be less than the number of variables in the object's class?

Tags: java

This is an excerpt from Oracle's Java tutorial website. It doesn't show the actual .java files, but I'm guessing "Rectangle" is a class. But if you note, the parameters passed down (by value?) for rectOne and rectTwo are different. (one has the origin variable while two does not)

If the object has certain number of parameters, can the actual number of passed down values be less than that? I'm assuming it can't be more by default.

Also, I searched for answers but cannot find.

```
// Declare and create a point object and two rectangle objects.
Point originOne = new Point(23, 94);
Rectangle rectOne = new Rectangle(originOne, 100, 200);
Rectangle rectTwo = new Rectangle(50, 100);
```

Comment: Looks like the Rectangle class specifies more than 1 constructor. Check out its documentation

Comment: Constructors can be overloaded so you can have multiple constructors which accepts different amount and type of arguments. Java doesn't allow default value for arguments, contrary to other languages, so there must be a constructor for each invocation required.

Comment: Not too sure what your asking, but the example shows a class "Rectangle" being instantiated twice (2 objects - rectOne, rectTwo) using different constructors for each one (assuming each are valid). The second constructor, rectTwo, may assume a default value for "origin" (Point object) if value is not passed in the constructor.

Answer (score 12):

An *object* doesn't have parameters - a method or a constructor does. In this case, basically there are two *overloaded* constructors. For example:

```
public Rectangle(Point origin, int width, int height)
{
    this.origin = origin;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
}

public Rectangle(int width, int height)
{
    this(Point.ZERO, width, height);
}
```

The only time in which the number of argument expressions for a single overload can vary is with varargs:

```
public void foo(String... bar)
{
    ...
}

foo("x"); // Equivalent to foo(new String[] { "x" })
foo("x", "y"); // Equivalent to foo(new String[] { "x", "y" })
foo("x", "y", "z"); // Equivalent to foo(new String[] { "x", "y", "z" })
```

Comment: Actually the number of arguments for vararg constructors doesn't change, you just hide the construction of the array under the hood.

Comment: @Jack: No, the number of *arguments* changes. For example, in the expression `foo("x", "y", "z")` there are three arguments. Sure, the compiler converts that into a single array to pass to the method, but the method invocation expression still has three arguments.

Comment: Ok, I'm aware of the overloaded constructors. So you're saying in this case, there are TWO constructors and not just one. That makes sense to me. If it was just one, I wasn't sure how the values were being passed down.

Comment: @el_kraken: Yes, that's what I'd expect given the example you've given. (It's *possible* that there's a single `Rectangle(Object... values)` constructor, but that seems very unlikely.

Comment: @JonSkeet: that's just syntactic sugar, nothing has to do with the semantics and overload resolution. Take this example: http://ideone.com/zUEQcQ. If vararg wasn't just syntactic sugar, then you couldn't resolve the correct overload for ambiguity but indeed you obtain no compile-time error. A vararg argument is just a single argument for a single overload. Passing it without the need of `new Type[]` is just synctatic sugar, even Oracle states that _The three periods after the final parameter's type indicate that the final __argument__ may be passed as an array or as a sequence of arguments._

Comment: @Jack: It absolutely has to do with overload resolution, in that part of the overload resolution algorithm is specifically about when varargs parameters are handled that way. That's how overload resolution *does* handle the ambiguity. The final argument from the *method's* perspective is a single value, but in terms of the source code, there are absolutely different numbers of arguments. Look at the grammar: there's an argument list. The argument list for `foo("x", "y", "z")` has three arguments - I find it hard to see how you'd deny that.

Comment: @Jack: I'd be happy to change "number of arguments" to "number of argument expressions" if that would make you more content (in fact, I'll do that now), given that that's the *precise* term the spec uses rather than "arguments", at least in the overload resolution section. If you'd still argue that `foo("x", "y", "z")` only has a single argument expression, then I don't think we'll ever see eye to eye...

Comment: @JonSkeet: that's fine. The main point is that, even if from a source code perspective you see three expressions, the actual signature is instead `Type[]` and only this type is considered in overload resolution. This distinction is rather relevant since you are talking about the grammar, I'm talking about the semantics. Having a vararg means having a single argument, that is conveniently auto generated from a comma separated list of arguments.

Comment: @Jack: But the signature specifies the *parameters*, not the arguments. Normally, when one talks about arguments, one refers to the expressions in the argument list, right? Heck, you've even said it yourself "conveniently auto generated from a comma separated list of arguments" - which means there are three arguments. If you had said to start with "it's the number of argument *expressions* that varies" that would have been considerably clearer. I think we both agree on what happens, but saying there's only one argument in the invocation `foo("x", "y", "z")` is confusing IMO.

Answer (score 1):

It's an exercise from the Classes topic. I read it too. You can create your own classes as the tutorials showed. Here you have 2 constructors for the class Rectangle1Class with different signatures. One accepts three parameters and the other only two. Try it and it will work. You have to create your class and methods to make it work. For example:

```
public Rectangle1Class(PointClass cOrigin, int cWidth, int cHeight){
    origin = cOrigin;
    width = cWidth;
    height = cHeight;
}

public Rectangle1Class(int cWidth, int cHeight){
    width = cWidth;
    height = cHeight;
}
```

Comment: Funny thing is after I got the answer here on this site, I went few pages after in that classes section which explained everything lol.

Comment: Yeah. That happened to me too but before reading that section I realized that I also could create my own classes so I decided to give it a shot and it worked. Read a lot and practice what you read. That's the best way to learn.

Answer (score 0):

Rectangle is a class and it has 2 constructors. 
One constructor takes in 3 parameters and the other takes 2.

While initializing objects you would have to make sure that you pass the required number of parameters as present in the constructors of the class.